# Using Mockito, how do I match against the key-value pair of a map?

Tags: java, mockito

I need to send a specific value from a mock object based on a specific key value.

From the concrete class:

```
map.put("xpath", "PRICE");
search(map);
```

From the test case:

```
IOurXMLDocument mock = mock(IOurXMLDocument.class);
when(mock.search(.....need help here).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

How do I mock this method call for this key value pair?

Answer (score 31):

I found this trying to solve a similar issue creating a Mockito stub with a Map parameter. I didn't want to write a custom matcher for the Map in question and then I found a more elegant solution: use the additional matchers in [hamcrest-library](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) with mockito's argThat:

```
when(mock.search(argThat(hasEntry("xpath", "PRICE"))).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

If you need to check against multiple entries then you can use other hamcrest goodies:

```
when(mock.search(argThat(allOf(hasEntry("xpath", "PRICE"), hasEntry("otherKey", "otherValue")))).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

This starts to get long with non-trivial maps, so I ended up extracting methods to collect the entry matchers and stuck them in our TestUtils:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anyOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
---------------------------------
public static <K, V> Matcher<Map<K, V>> matchesEntriesIn(Map<K, V> map) {
    return allOf(buildMatcherArray(map));
}

public static <K, V> Matcher<Map<K, V>> matchesAnyEntryIn(Map<K, V> map) {
    return anyOf(buildMatcherArray(map));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <K, V> Matcher<Map<? extends K, ? extends V>>[] buildMatcherArray(Map<K, V> map) {
    List<Matcher<Map<? extends K, ? extends V>>> entries = new ArrayList<Matcher<Map<? extends K, ? extends V>>>();
    for (K key : map.keySet()) {
        entries.add(hasEntry(key, map.get(key)));
    }
    return entries.toArray(new Matcher[entries.size()]);
}
```

So I'm left with:

```
when(mock.search(argThat(matchesEntriesIn(map))).thenReturn("$100.00");
when(mock.search(argThat(matchesAnyEntryIn(map))).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

There's some ugliness associated with the generics and I'm suppressing one warning, but at least it's DRY and hidden away in the TestUtil.

One last note, beware the [embedded hamcrest issues in JUnit 4.10](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2012/10/whats-up-with-junit-and-hamcrest.html). With Maven, I recommend importing hamcrest-library first and then JUnit 4.11 (now 4.12) and exclude hamcrest-core from JUnit just for good measure:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

Edit: Sept 1, 2017 - Per some of the comments, I updated my answer to show my Mockito dependency, my imports in the test util, and a junit that is running green as of today:

```
import static blah.tool.testutil.TestUtil.matchesAnyEntryIn;
import static blah.tool.testutil.TestUtil.matchesEntriesIn;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Map<Integer, String> expected = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        expected.put(1, "One");
        expected.put(3, "Three");

        Map<Integer, String> actual = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        actual.put(1, "One");
        actual.put(2, "Two");

        assertThat(actual, matchesAnyEntryIn(expected));

        expected.remove(3);
        expected.put(2, "Two");
        assertThat(actual, matchesEntriesIn(expected));
    }

    @Test
    public void mockitoTest() {
        SystemUnderTest sut = mock(SystemUnderTest.class);
        Map<Integer, String> expected = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        expected.put(1, "One");
        expected.put(3, "Three");

        Map<Integer, String> actual = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        actual.put(1, "One");

        when(sut.search(argThat(matchesAnyEntryIn(expected)))).thenReturn("Response");
        assertThat(sut.search(actual), is("Response"));
    }

    protected class SystemUnderTest {
        // We don't really care what this does
        public String search(Map<Integer, String> map) {
            if (map == null) return null;
            return map.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a handy solution. Curiously though, I was getting a "Wrong argument type, expecting Map<String, String> found Map<? extends String, ? extends String>" that java couldn't seem to resolve with any amount of prodding and import tweaking. I had to change my mocked class's method to accept a `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>` to get it to work. Any thoughts? I have the same dependency versions for junit and hamcrest as you; my Mockito is v. 1.9.5.

Comment: @PatrickM did you manage to resolve the generics issue in a cleaner fashion? From the above I have exactly the same problem but am unable to change the collection generic types...

Comment: @AndrewEells, no, I never found a solution. I switched from Hamcrest and started using AssertJ, which seems to need far less type coercion for its assertions.

Comment: @PatrickM, AndrewEells - I've not seen your issue. I recreated the test util and a test case using the above and it is still working. Curious about your AssertJ solution as well, maybe you could share it as a new answer?

Comment: Hmm now that you mention it, AssertJ doesn't really have a solution for removing the requirement on Hamcrest matchers from Mockito's `when` interface. That's where I was having a problem with the type coercion, not the assertions as I indicated in my previous comment. I can't even recall which project I had to do they type tweaking in, much less the unit test. (But I'm pretty sure I had to leave it with the `? extends String` syntax.)

Comment: An offhand improvement - use anonymous classes init to populate the maps, e.g.: `new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{ put(1, "One"); put(2, "Two"); }};` etc.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to "match" against a particular Map, you can use some of the answers above, or a custom "matcher" Object that extends Map<X, Y>, or an ArgumentCaptor, like this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Map> argumentsCaptured = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
verify(mock, times(1)).method((Map<String, String>) argumentsCaptured.capture());
assert argumentsCaptured.getValue().containsKey("keynameExpected"); 
// argumentsCaptured.getValue() will be the first Map it called it with.
// argumentsCaptured.getAllValues() if it was called more than times(1)
```

See also more answers here: [Verify object attribute value with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1142837/32453)

If you want to capture multiple maps:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Map> argumentsCaptured = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Map> argumentsCaptured2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
verify(mock, times(1)).method(argumentsCaptured.capture(), argumentsCaptured2.capture());
assert argumentsCaptured.getValue().containsKey("keynameExpected"); 
assert argumentsCaptured2.getValue().containsKey("keynameExpected2"); 
....
```

Comment: Note that this answer works also if you want to check only some key / value pairs equality between expected and actual. This is handy if some values are not mockable. + 1 vote

Comment: What if the method requires multiple maps to be passed and captured?

Comment: OK added an example of multiple

Answer (score 8):

For anyone arriving to this question like myself, there's actually a very simple solution based on Lambdas:

```
when(mock.search(argThat(map -> "PRICE".equals(map.get("xpath"))))).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

Explanation: `argThat` expects an `ArgumentMatcher` which is a functional interface and thus can be written as a Lambda.

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant way how to do it.

Comment: This is a nice, modern solution, especially for simple use cases.

Comment: To avoid NPE I needed to use the `doReturn` format, e.g `doReturn("$100.00").when(mock).search(argThat(map -> "PRICE".equals(map.get("xpath")));`

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't this work?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("xpath", "PRICE");
when(mock.search(map)).thenReturn("$100.00");
```

The `Map` parameter should behave the same way as other parameters.

Comment: There is missing one closing bracket.

Comment: IOurXMLDocument 
represents our service layer that I do not want to call for my unit tests. For 1 situation we are calling it twice with 2 different map values. Instead I want to inspect the value and return a fixed result.  So when the application code does the following:

   map.put("xpath", "PRODUCTNAME");
   when(mock.search(map)).thenReturn("Candybar");

Comment: Shouldn't be mock.search(eq(map)) so it check the actual map equality?

Comment: this does not work. Using equality matcher on map does not work too.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like what you need is an `Answer`:

```
IOurXMLDocument doc = mock(IOurXMLDocument.class);
when(doc.search(Matchers.<Map<String,String>>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        String value = map.get("xpath");
        if ("PRICE".equals(value)) {
            return "$100.00";
        } else if ("PRODUCTNAME".equals(value)) {
            return "Candybar";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

But what seems like a better idea is to not use primitive `Map` as parameter to your search method - you could probably transform this map into a pojo with `price` and `productName` attributes. Just an idea :)

Comment: I haven't needed `Answer`, but those `Matchers.<Map<String,String>>any()` syntax was really helpful, thanks!!