# How to compare new Date in unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have `service` with method :

```
Entity entity = new Entity(new Date(), 1, 2L);
return entityRepository.save(entity);
```

And my test :

```
@Test
public void testSaveEntity() {
    Entity entity = new Entity(new Date(), 1, 2L);
    entityService.saveEntity(1, 2L);
    verify(entityRepository, times(1)).save(entity);
}
```

If `Entity` `equals()` not compared `Date` then everything is all right but if compare `Date` then
test throws out `Argument(s) are different!`

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using `Date`?

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Despite the name a `Date` does not represent a date but a point in time with millisecond precision. So if you called `new Date()` with a few milliseconds in between, you were most likely getting two objects that were not equal. Confusing, yes. Use java.time and as Lesiak says, use `java.time.Clock`.

Comment: Java has *two* `Date` classes, `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. Both are terribly flawed, and should be avoided. Both were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically replaced by `Instant` and `LocalDate`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it is impossible to change the service and the entity. Then in such cases it is better to use `ArgumentMatcher<>` in `Mockito`.

**Step 1 :**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EntityMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<Entity> {

    private Entity left;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Entity right) {
        return (left.getEventDate().getTime() - right.getEventDate().getTime() <= 1000));
    }
}
```

Here you ovverride `equals` which will be compare objects. `mathces` can be `ovveride` as you like. I think the difference in one second is enough.

**Step 2:**

```
verify(entityRepository).save(argThat(new EntityMatcher(new Entity(new Date(), 1, 2L))));
```

**Other case :**
Most likely, in other tests, such a situation may arise that this `entity` will also need to be checked `when`

```
when(entityRepository.save(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(new Entity(new Date(), 1, 2L));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1: Use Clock class to control time**

Instead of using `new Date()`:

- inject a `Clock` instance to your service
- use its methods to retrieve current time
- In your test code, use `Clock.fixed` to control current time

See [Guide to the Java Clock Class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-clock)

**Option 1: Relax your matching requirements**

Use [Mockito ArgumentMatchers](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers) to relax mtching requirements - use `any(YourEntity.class)` to match any `YourEntity`, or write a custom argument matcher for your Entity.

Comment: Unfortanetly, `Clock` I can't change it. `any(Date.class)` seems to be used in the `when()` construction

Comment: 1. I'm sorry but I don't understand. Do you mean you cannot change your code? 2. You can use argument matchers in `verify` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may be having an issue with the definition of your `equals` method.
You should define under which circumstances two different Entities are considered equal:

**Are two Entities equal only if their date value is within the same

millisecond or do we only care about seconds, minutes or days?**

Similar to handling floating point values, this acceptable difference can be calculated similar to [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `equals` method used in your solution:

```
verify(entityRepository, times(1)).save(entity);
```

you could try to capture the Argument and assert it in the next step as described in [Verify object attribute value with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142837/verify-object-attribute-value-with-mockito)

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Entity> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
verify(entityRepository, times(1)).save((argument.capture());
assertEquals(1, argument.getValue().getWhatever());
```